# How to set values to np.nan with multiple conditions for series?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   x   R   i   R   nan h
1   z   g   j   x a   nan
2   z   h   nan y nan nan
3   x   g   nan nan nan nan
4   x   x   h   x   s   f
```

I want to replace all the cells where:

1. the value in row 0 is R (`df.loc[0] == 'R'`)
2. the cell is not 'x' (`!= 'x'`)
3. only rows 2 and below (2:)

with `np.nan`.

Essentially I want to do:

```
df.loc[2:,df.loc[0]=='R']!='x' = np.nan
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to comparison
```

I just don't know how the syntax is supposed to be.

I've tried

```
df[df.loc[2:,df.loc[0]=='R']!='x']
```

but this doesn't list the values I want.

Comment: Please post expected output also.

Comment: Wait a minute, you have already done it? You just have to assign the value np.nan in second case

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

```
mask = df.ne('x') & df.iloc[0].eq('R')
mask.iloc[:2] = False

df.mask(mask)

   A    B    C    D    E    F
0  x    R    i    R  NaN    h
1  z    g    j    x    a  NaN
2  z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  x    x    h    x    s    f
```

#### Explanation

Build the mask up

1. `df.ne('x')` gives

   ```
           A      B     C      D     E     F
    0  False   True  True   True  True  True
    1   True   True  True  False  True  True
    2   True   True  True   True  True  True
    3  False   True  True   True  True  True
    4  False  False  True  False  True  True
   ```
2. But we want that in conjunction with `df.iloc[0].eq('R')` which is a `Series`.  Turns out that if we just `&` those two together, it will align the `Series` index with the columns of the mask in step 1.

   ```
    A    False
    B     True
    C    False
    D     True
    E    False
    F    False
    Name: 0, dtype: bool

    # &

           A      B     C      D     E     F
    0  False   True  True   True  True  True
    1   True   True  True  False  True  True
    2   True   True  True   True  True  True
    3  False   True  True   True  True  True
    4  False  False  True  False  True  True

    # GIVES YOU

           A      B      C      D      E      F
    0  False   True  False   True  False  False
    1  False   True  False  False  False  False
    2  False   True  False   True  False  False
    3  False   True  False   True  False  False
    4  False  False  False  False  False  False
   ```
3. Finally, we want to exclude the first two rows from these shenanigans so...

   ```
    mask.iloc[:2] = False
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
mask = df.iloc[0] !='R'

df.loc[2:, mask] = df.loc[2:,mask].where(df.loc[2:,mask]=='x')
```

Output:

```
     A  B    C    D    E    F
0    x  R    i    R  NaN    h
1    z  g    j    x    a  NaN
2  NaN  h  NaN    y  NaN  NaN
3    x  g  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4    x  x  NaN    x  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

By your approach:

```
df[df.loc[2:,df.loc[0]=='R']!='x']=np.nan
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A    B    C    D    E    F
0  x    R    i    R  NaN    h
1  z    g    j    x    a  NaN
2  z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  x    x    h    x    s    f
```